# Something about "information" and "insights"

Tags: differences, language-formation

In this sentence,

> Sharing insights and answers freely is what makes the Internet such a great medium for learning.

Why is "information " not the right answer?

Comment: Answer to what question?

Comment: Try to understand the difference in the meanings of *information* and *insight* -- they are very different. Sharing information is a simple exchange of details about something. Sharing insights is about expressing what one understood from those details -- how one interprets, analyses and draws inferences from the information. See the dictionaries and update your question with what you found.

Answer (score 1):

Insight explains how and why things happen while information just shows what happened.. From internet, we get in-depth knowledge and to provide such knowledge to the viewers **Insight** is necessary rather than **information**

These links will clarify the meaning of Insight and information in more detail:

1) http://www.visioncritical.co.uk/blog/information-v-insight/

2) http://giveitsomesparkle.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/internal-communications-the-difference-between-information-and-insight/

Comment: In **Dragnet**, Detective Joe Friday gathered *information* ("Just the facts, Ma'am"). He then shared his *insights* with his partner (and the audience).